# Black Ops 1 and Modern Warfare 2 aren't saving multiplayer progress?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I was playing Black Ops on the PS3 and it didn't save my multiplayer progress. I had earned got a few levels, left the game, and went back in, and there was nothing. This also happened on mw2.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I checked through menus and options and it was just dead ends.

Comment: Might seem like a silly question, but are you playing on the same PS3 user account?

Comment: yes im on the same account